# Dados sendo duplicados nos atributos date dentro de um foreach

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de classificação por estrelas onde eu listo os *posts* e mostra classificação. O problema está nos *posts* que recebem a mesma nota. Não esta pegando a nota de cada *post* e sim de um único *post* e mostrando a mesma nota nos demais.

No banco de dados, tenho a tabela *post* e nela tem os campos `pontos` e `votos` onde no `foreach` usando o php divido os pontos pelos votos e arredondo o valor e envio para o campo `data-average` que fica numa `span` e no *javascript pego esse valor e manipulo a `span` aumentando o `width` que tem um *background amarelo* e por cima tem uma `span` com fundo de uma estrela.

Esse e meu código `php`:

```
<?php
 $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id_post , pontos , votos  FROM posts LIMIT 3 ");

$return = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 foreach ($return as $dados) {

$calculo = ($dados->pontos == 0) ? 0 : round(($dados->pontos / $dados->votos), 1); ?>

 <span class="ratingAverage" data-average="<?=$calculo ;?>"></span>

 <span  data-id="<?= $dados->id_post; ?>"></span><div class="barra"><span class="bg"></span><span class="stars">

 <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?><span class="star" data-vote="<?php echo $i; ?>"><span class="starAbsolute"></span></span>

 <?php endfor; echo '</span></div><p class="votos vt"><span>' . $dados->votos . '</span> votos</p>';

  ?><?php }  ?>
```

Meu `css`:

```
.barra{width:150px; height:30px; background:#ebebeb; position:relative;}
.stars{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%;}
.star{float:left;width:30px;height:30px; text-align:center; position:relative;cursor:pointer;}
.star.full{background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f)}
.bg{float:left;height:30px; width:30%; background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f);}
.starAbsolute{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:url(/assets/img/config/v12/starpng.png) top left no-repeat;  background-size:cover;}
```

Meu `javascript`:

```
$(function() {
    var average = $('.ratingAverage').attr('data-average');
    function avaliacao(average) {
        average = (Number(average) * 20);

        $('.bg-').css('width', 0);
        $('.barra- .bg-').animate({width: average + '%'}, 500);
    }
    avaliacao(average);
});
```

Esse é o código *HTML* quando executado:

```
<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4"></span>
<span  data-id="1"></span><div class="barra-"><span class="bg-"></span><span class="stars-">
<span class="star-" data-vote="1"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="2"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="3"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="4"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="5"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span></span></div><p class="votos vt"><span>1</span> votos</p>  

<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4"></span>
 <span  data-id="2"></span><div class="barra-"><span class="bg-"></span><span class="stars-">
<span class="star-" data-vote="1"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="2"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="3"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="4"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="5"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span></span></div><p class="votos vt"><span>2</span> votos</p>  

<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="4"></span>
<span  data-id="3"></span><div class="barra-"><span class="bg-"></span><span class="stars-">
<span class="star-" data-vote="1"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="2"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="3"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="4"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span><span class="star-" data-vote="5"><span class="starAbsolute-"></span></span></span></div><p class="votos vt"><span>3</span> votos</p>
```

Fica dessa maneira, se olhar na *span* onde tem o atributo `date-avarege` deveria pegar os votos de cada `id` e não é o que acontece. Ele pega o valor do primeiro e joga para restantes, ficando o restante com voto 4 da primeira id

Comment: Você já verificou se a linha round(($dados->pontos / $dados->votos), 1) não está retornando sempre o mesmo valor, ou seja no seu banco de dados os campos pontos e votos quando dividos dão o mesmo valor.

Comment: eu vi ele  esta retornando o mesmo valor mais como resolvo ja que ele era para pegar o valor de cada id dos campos votos e pontos era par a funcionar ja que a variavel calculo esta dentro do foreach como faço para ele percorrer cada id

Comment: O que eu quiz dizer é se os valores amazenados na tabela posts não são iguais.

Comment: nao sao ele so pega os pontos e votos do 1 id e replica no outros no id 2 3 4 5 tem votos e pontos diferentes

Comment: o erro esta no java script eu acho pois ele esta dando o mesmo valor para as demais